# Missing Database Table Error: Database table supports for model Support was not found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I'm building a controller for a legacy CakePHP2.5 application, the controller loads an existing model then query data from the table for that model, when call the controller I keep getting the error message below

[image]

```
Missing Database Table Error: Database table supports for model Support was not found.
```

below is the Support Controller code

```
<?php
class SupportController extends AppController{
    public $name='Support';
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    


    public function index(){
        $this->loadModel('Applicant');

        $appConditions = array(
            'fields'=>array('first_name','surname','middle_name','maiden_name','date_of_birth'),
            'order'=>array('Applicant.created DESC')
        );

        $this->paginate['Applicant'] = $appConditions;
        $applicationData = $this->paginate('Applicant');

        $this->set(compact('applicationData'));

        // $this->set('applicants', $this->Applicant->find('all'));
    }
}
```

The controller does not require a model as it is suppose to load data from the applicant model which already exists.

Comment: Why not use [uses](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) to tell it that the model for this controller is Applicant?

Answer (score 1):

it seems cakephp requires the use of var $uses = null or public $uses = array(); ; to be declared in all controllers without a model, to resolve the error I had to declare a public

```
public $uses = array();

<?php
class NameController extends AppController{
    public $name='Name';
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $uses = array();
    
    public function index(){
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Or `$uses = array('Applicant');` and then you don't need to `$this->loadModel('Applicant');`.